# Android webview

Tags: android, webview

**Edit**
*edited question to clarify question and unmotivated formatting and readability.*

I have a webview in which I have implemented an Override of WebResourceResponse in the webview.

```
WebResourceResponse shouldinterceptrequest ( Webview view, WebResourceRequest request);
```

Could someone help me understand how that call works? For example how would you share cookies with request? Then parse the response. Reading the documentation i can't find how to intercept the response from the site to the webview.

**Solution**
*I ended up figuring out that I was going about this all wrong. I was trying to use the request and responses made from the webview to emulate the browser.  I ended up discovering it was much easier to emulate the browser making direct http calls using URlHttpConnection. The webview was pointless because I was just trying to get json data and had the webview hidden.*

Comment: Thanks its hard to style your questions on a phone.

Comment: what is the question

Comment: do you get the json array successfully ?

Comment: My webview gets the jsonarray and populates the tables with it. But when I try to "copy" the array so to speak by doing

Comment: So you need to  copy that json array in order to access it as global variable right ? do you receive any kind of json response during the process ?or you receive json object  one time

Comment: Sorry I had to make a comment since my phone hit enter. My webview gets the jsonarray and populates the tables with it. But when I try to "copy" the array so to speak by doing webresourceresponse response = new shouldinteruptresponse (view, request)..... that allows me to do  response.getData (), response.getResponseHeaders () but they all end up with nullpointerexceptions

Comment: Please read my edited comment

Comment: The request is a xmlhttprequest made by some javascripts that are embeded in the url done at for example.        Www.example.com request url is www.example.com/example/1/1 the type is application/json. Done by a GET that sends userverification with request.

Comment: Sorry yes i need to get json array as a global variable. And it loads the json on first load of url then every 5 minutes it reloads the json to check for table updates.

Comment: Can you detect the json once  it load ?

Comment: I thought it was loaded. Byt that would explain the nullexception. How would I go about that. Something like int ready = read (response.getData). If ready==-1 then something like InputStreamReader = response.getData ()?

Comment: I solved this problem will post solution this afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ohttpurlconnection. Made a connection shared the webviews cookies and was able to get the json response directly. But alas I got caught and they locked of the holes I was getting it from. Oh well good learning experiance.